# is "HttpWebRequest" using of my site's Bandwidth?

Tags: url, httpwebrequest, hidden, bandwidth

I want to read mp3 file from external url and hide url path for client in my website.
I'm using this code:

```
//Create a stream for the file
    Stream stream = null;

    //This controls how many bytes to read at a time and send to the client
    int bytesToRead = 10000;

    // Buffer to read bytes in chunk size specified above
    byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];

    // The number of bytes read
    try
    {
        //Create a WebRequest to get the file
        HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.alsacreations.fr/mp3/everywhere.mp3");

        //Create a response for this request
        HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();

        if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
            fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;

        //Get the Stream returned from the response
        stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();

        // prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
        var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        //Indicate the type of data being sent
        resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        //Name the file 
        string fileName = "everywhere.mp3";
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName);
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());

        int length;
        do
        {
            // Verify that the client is connected.
            if (resp.IsClientConnected)
            {
                // Read data into the buffer.
                length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                // and write it out to the response's output stream
                resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                // Flush the data
                resp.Flush();

                //Clear the buffer
                buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
            }
            else
            {
                // cancel the download if client has disconnected
                length = -1;
            }
        } while (length > 0); //Repeat until no data is read
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            //Close the input stream
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

This code is work correctly, My question is for download this mp3 file(http://www.alsacreations.fr/mp3/everywhere.mp3) use **My Site's BandWidth** or not?

Comment: Why posting code when having question not about code, but what BandWidth to use?

Comment: By this method I have used to show the mp3 files from another server, my site's bandwidth is used or not?